# How to import type in vue3 setup script with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite

I want to use `<script setup>` feature with props type check in typescript.
But it seems that `<script setup>` didn't import RouteRecordRaw as a type but as a value?
And if I run this code in vite, the browser console will print an error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/vue-router.js?v=52a879a7' does not provide an export named 'RouteRecordRaw'"

Code:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";
// VSCode will print an error: "RouteRecordRaw" only refers to a type, butisbeing used as a value here. (TS2693) 

import { defineProps } from "vue";

const props = defineProps<{
  routeList: Array<RouteRecordRaw>;
}>();

const renderRoutes = props.routeList;
</script>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this:

```js
import type { RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";
```

[More info](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta/#type-only-imports-exports)